# Expresion regular Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

Quiero hacer una expresión regular en Javascript para el siguiente string: ej_test.PNg. Necesito que solo sea .png pero que png pueda ser mayúsculas, minúsculas todas o una o varias de sus letras.

Comment: Las expresiones regulares pueden ser "case insensitive" incluyendo la opcion 'i'

Comment: Saludos, @ArnauCastellví. Actualizé mi respuesta con lo que has dicho del flag i.

Comment: ¿Qué has intentado o investigado?. En [es.so] se pide un mínimo de esfuerzo, no acostumbramos a resolver la vida a los demás sin que muestren que han intentado algo. Te invito a leer [ask] y a realizar el [tour]. Saludos

Comment: ¡Tu pregunta parece un [ticket para desarrollo](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4433)! Lee [ask].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No sé si es la mejor solución ni la más óptima, pero te presento lo que se me ocurrió:

```
/\.[Pp][Nn][Gg]$/
```

¿Cómo funciona?

- `/` Iniciamos la expresión regular
- `\.` Busca un punto (la barra invertida de delante está porque el punto es una palabra reservada que significa "cualquier carácter", y sin él, cogería cualquier carácter en vez de un punto)
- `[Pp]` Busca una letra P, sea mayúscula o minúscula
- `[Nn]` Busca una letra N, sea mayúscula o minúscula
- `[Gg]` Busca una letra G, sea mayúscula o minúscula
- `$` El símbolo de dólar significa el final de la frase, es decir, buscará que .PNG esté al final (de esta forma, no cogerá como válido hola.png.txt, porque .png no está al final).
- `/` Indica que terminamos la expresión regular.

### ACTUALIZACIÓN

Viendo el comentario de @ArnauCastellví, podemos simplificarlo mucho más, aún.

El resultado sería este:

```
/\.png$/i
```

¿Cómo funciona?

- `/` Iniciamos la expresión regular
- `\.` Busca un punto (la barra invertida de delante está porque el punto es una palabra reservada que significa "cualquier carácter", y sin él, cogería cualquier carácter en vez de un punto)
- `png` Busca png en el texto
- `$` El símbolo de dólar significa el final de la frase, es decir, buscará que .PNG esté al final (de esta forma, no cogerá como válido hola.png.txt, porque .png no está al final).
- `/` Indica que terminamos la expresión regular.
- `i` Avisa de que no debe tener en cuenta las mayúsculas y las minúsculas (será *case **i**nsensitive*)

¡Espero que te haya servido! No sé mucho de regex, es lo máximo que he podido sacar.

Comment: muchas gracias @tupi me funciono la primera parte, así he solucionado mi problema: ^([A-Z]|[a-z]|_|-|[0-9])+.[Pp][Nn][Gg]$

Comment: Evita responder este tipo de preguntas que no muestran un mínimo de esfuerzo o investigación, ya que por lo general terminan carradas y tu aporte se pierde. Saludos

Comment: De acuerdo, @MauricioContreras, lo tendré en cuenta para la próxima. ¡Muchas gracias!